# What should be the column order , when creating indexes on a Partitioned Table

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

Partitioned Table Question.

When creating indexes on a Partition table ( Fact Table) , we always include the column that is the basis for the partitioning in the index. This column is also ALWAYS used in the where clause when accessing the data.

When creating the primary key /  non unique indexes ; should the column used for partitioning be used as the first or second column in the index ?

Scenario

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl1] (
    [EventKey]  INT              NOT NULL,
    [Tbl1Id]               BIGINT           NOT NULL,
    [FK_Tbl2Id]            BIGINT           NOT NULL,
    < many other data columns>
) ON [psEvent] ([EventKey]);
```

The PartitionFunction (pfEvent) for the partition scheme is partitioned on EventKey , with each unique EventKey  being it’s own unique partition , in a unique file/filegroup. We create the Partitions/ Files/ FilesGroup in advance of the EventKey being used.

The table is around 2 billion rows
We currently have 2,500 unique values for EventKey
The column Tbl1ID has very high cardinality (no more than 5 occurrences of any value, but quite often the value is unique)
The column FK_Tbl2Id has high cardinality (approx  50 occurrences of any value)
There is zero Update activity, ie data is inserted for an EventKey in a single batch , and is never modified.
Data is delete on an ad hoc basis us the following statement

```
Declare @PartitionKey INT= $PARTITION.pfEvent(<Event Key being deleted>)
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Tbl1 WITH (PARTITIONS (@PartitionKey));
```

Should we create the Primary clustered key as

```
[PK_tbl1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Tbl1Id] ASC, [EventKey] ASC) ON [psEvent] ([EventKey]
```

Or as

```
[PK_tbl1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EventKey] ASC, [Tbl1Id] ASC,) ON [psEvent] ([EventKey]
```

Similarly for a non-clustered index  should it be created as

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [tbl1_Tbl2I _idx]
    ON [dbo].[Tbl1]([FK_Tbl2Id] ASC, [EventKey] ASC) ON [psEvent] ([EventKey]);
```

Or as

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [tbl1_Tbl2I _idx]
    ON [dbo].[Tbl1]([EventKey] ASC, [FK_Tbl2Id] ASC) ON [psEvent] ([EventKey]);
```

I have written a query as

```
select  t1.Tbl1Id,<some t1 columns data Columns>  
from dbo.tbl12 t2  
inner join dbo.tbl1 t1 
   on t1.Eventkey=t2.EventKey and  t1.FK_Tbl2ID=t2.TBl2ID
where t2.EventKey=@EventKey
```

When I look at the execution plan the query is using [PK_tbl1] index to join to tbl1 and takes a long time to run.  If I add a "WITH (INDEX(tbl1_Tbl2I _idx))"  after the join to tbl1 then the query runs a lot better.

Tbl2 s also partition in the same manner as Tbl1

Comment: It would help to know if `tbl12` is also partitioned (and how). You don't say which of the alternative index definitions were in place when you tested. Providing the post-execution (actual) plan for the slow and fast cases would also help. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ is a convenient place to upload plans. Include links to the plans in your question.

Comment: @PaulWhite  - I see my question more of a table design / best practices question rather than a "Solve the performance issue " question. We have a  large database (over 20 TB) with approx 30 partition tables , some of these table have  100+ billion rows.    Some of the tables also contain spatial data data which is indexed , SQL Server does not support the partitioning of Spatial  Indexes.

I am looking for some guidance in the best way to design my indexes.

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/51349/1192